# Why doesn't my function work in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Why won't my function work in Google Sheets? Why can't I get a formula to work inside an IF function?

```
=IF(B2=0,0,800*2(B2-1))
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The *formula* doesn't work in Google Sheets because it's not using the correct syntax: an operator is missing between `2` and `(`.  Please checkout [Add formulas & functions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46977?hl=en) to learn the basics of Google Sheets formulas.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the ^ symbol, next time i'll pay more attention to my equation!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was caused by a typo.